# reducing array of objects by filtering array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, big-o, reduce

my function is sent an array of ids as strings and returns an array of objects. It works, which is great! But i am sure that there is a more elegant solution. i'm iterating over the array, then the foreach iterates over a second array and if it finds a match, iterates over a third array to check for duplicates.

```
myMethod: state => (argsArray) => {

    const myCampaigns = argsArray.reduce((acc, num) => {
      state.campaigns.forEach(item => {
        if (item.segmentIds.includes(num) && !acc.includes(item)) {
          acc.push(item)
        }
      })
      return acc
    }, [])

    return myCampaigns
  }
```

Comment: Looks like javascript.  Consider adding javascript tag to question.  Edit: I tried to do it for you: max 5 tags...

Comment: can you share some input data and expected output for better clarity of your question?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your code, the initial values look like this:

```js
state = {
  campaigns: [
    {segmentIds:[1,2,3]}, {segmentIds:[4,5,6], ...}
  ]
}
argsArray = [1, 3, 6]
```

There is a double iteration in your code, making your runtime quadratic... not ideal.

What you want is avoid nested iterations. One way you could do that is by creating a variable containing all your segmentIds making look-ups easier to handle. Also try and use Javascript's [Set data type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as it comes with very good look-up time complexity.

A possible solution for your problem:

```js
// store all your segmentIds before your iteration
// and flatten your array
const segmentIds = state.campaigns
  .reduce((accumulator, campaign) => {
    return campaign.segmentIds.reduce((acc, id) => {
      if (acc.has(id)) return acc;
      acc.add(id);
      return acc;
    }, accumulator);
  }, new Set());
//
const myCampaigns = argsArray.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if (segmentIds.has(num) && !acc.includes(item)) {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable with the double-reduce, you can try and use [Lodash's flatten method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten):

```js
const segmentIds = _.flatten(
  state.campaigns.map(campaign => campaign.segmentIds)
)
```